# Is the following code true? for copying text in Notepad java app?

Tags: java, notepad

I'm creating a Notepad application in Java using NetBeans! The event for copying text is as follows: But it displays an error about '.setContents' indicating that "cannot find symbol" 
I've tried to remove the error but couldn't..

```
import java.awt.FileDialog; 
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor; 
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection; 
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable; 
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.DataOutputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.StringReader; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

private void CopyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String sel=TextArea.getSelectedText();
    StringSelection clipString=new StringSelection(sel);
    TextArea.setContents(clipString,clipString); 
}
```

Comment: _"cannot find symbol"_ what symbol?

Comment: @RafaEl "setContents"

Comment: Could you provide your `import` lines (at the top of the `.java` file)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `TextArea` variable. Look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) for further reference.

Comment: TextArea is a variable name of my JTextArea

Answer (score 0):

This error might mean that you need to import StringSelection or TextArea, depending on what symbol it can't find. The error is a bit vague since it's complaining about the method call on TextArea but the compiler might just not be able to make sense of your code.

Additionally, it seems you're attempting to statically call a method on TextArea that should be called on an instance, but you probably won't see that compile error before you fix your imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do like this.

```
private void CopyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String sel=TextArea.getSelectedText();
```

You can either replace the TextArea contents with the copied text or add the copied text after the contents of TextArea.

```
    // if you want to replace the contents of the TextArea with the copied text
    TextArea.setText(sel);
```

or

```
    //if you want to add the copied text to the end of the text in the TextArea
    TextArea.append(sel);
}
```